# JUnit Mockito object initialization in method

Tags: java, junit, initialization, mockito

I am using Mockito's `when` and `thenReturn` function and am wondering if there's a way for the object inside to be initialized in the test functions. So for example if I had:

```
public class fooTest {
    private Plane plane;
    private Car car;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {          
        Mockito.when(Car.findById(eq(plane.getId()))).thenReturn(plane);
    }

    @Test
    public void isBlue() {
        plane = new Plane();
        plane.setId(2);
        Plane result = Car.findById(car);
        assertEquals(Color.BLUE, result.getColor());
    }
}
```

Obviously the above code doesn't work because it throws a null pointer exception but the idea is to initialize the plane object in every test function and have mockito's `when` use *that* object. I suppose I could put the `when` line in every function after the Plane object has been initialized and set but that makes the code look very ugly. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Could you provide the `Plane` and `Car` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I dont know your `Plane` or `Car` class, am going to make some assumptions in the `test` class.
I dont know what you are trying to test, If you are trying to `test` `Car` , you shouldnt ideally `mock` your class under `test`.
Any way you can do something like this in your `setUp` method.

```
public class fooTest {

    private Plane plane;
    @Mock
    private Car car;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {   
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);       
        plane = new Plane();
        plane.setId(2);
        plane.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        Mockito.when(car.findById(eq(plane.getId()))).thenReturn(plane);
    }

    @Test
    public void isBlue() {
       // There is no point in testing car since the result is already mocked.
        Plane result = car.findById(2);
        assertEquals(Color.BLUE, result.getColor());
    }
}
```